# How to get rid of denominator in numerator and denominator in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have the following expression

```
(-1 + 1/p)^B/(-1 + (-1 + 1/p)^(A + B))
```

How can I multiply both the denominator and numberator by p^(A+B), i.e. to get rid of the denominators in both numerator and denominator? I tried varous Expand, Factor, Simplify etc. but none of them worked.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you question, you may teach Mma some algebra:

```
r = {(k__ + Power[a_, b_]) Power[c_, b_] -> (k Power[c, b] + Power[a c, b]),
      p_^(a_ + b_) q_^a_ -> p^b ( q p)^(a),
      (a_ + b_) c_ -> (a c + b c)
    }
```

and then define

```
s1 = ((-1 + 1/p)^B/(-1 + (-1 + 1/p)^(A + B)))

f[a_, c_] := (Numerator[a ] c //. r)/(Denominator[a ] c //. r)
```

So that

```
f[s1, p^(A + B)]
```

is

```
((1 - p)^B*p^A)/((1 - p)^(A + B) - p^(A + B))
```

[image]

Comment: amazing! How did you come up with those rules? Why not other rules?

Comment: @Qiang I just did the transformation by hand and wrote down the rules I used ... not very "automatic"

Answer (score 3):

I must say I did not understand the original question.  However, while trying to understand the intriguing solution given by belisarius I came up with the following:

```
expr = (-1 + 1/p)^B/(-1 + (-1 + 1/p)^(A + B));

Together@(PowerExpand@FunctionExpand@Numerator@expr/
 PowerExpand@FunctionExpand@Denominator@expr)
```

Output (as given by belisarius):

[image]

Alternatively:

```
PowerExpand@FunctionExpand@Numerator@expr/PowerExpand@
 FunctionExpand@Denominator@expr
```

gives

[image]

or

```
FunctionExpand@Numerator@expr/FunctionExpand@Denominator@expr
```

[image]

Thanks to belisarius for another nice lesson in the power of Mma.

Comment: +1 I think teaching Mma to render your formulae in "elegant" ways is more an art than a craft.

Answer (score 0):

Simplify should work, but in your case it doesn't make sense to multiply numerator and denominator by p^(A+B), it doesn't cancel denominators